# Конвертировать строку в Hex JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Нужно переделать код PHP в JS.

```
$bin_key = pack("H*",'e0sitcs5zd51wuauz8r65c1jqxtc1tsojt4mtk2lbd4ak2x2tf');
```

Этот фрагмент надо переделать на JS.

Пробовал все и:

```
Buffer('e0sitcs5zd51wuauz8r65c1jqxtc1tsojt4mtk2lbd4ak2x2tf', 'hex')
```

и устанавливал locutus:

```
pack('H*', 'e0sitcs5zd51wuauz8r65c1jqxtc1tsojt4mtk2lbd4ak2x2tf')
```

Ничего не выходит. В первом случае, из всей строки получает только 2 символа. Во втором, строка с неопознанными знаками. Естественно, результат не сходится с PHP.резульат в PHP - lmFaDyQtd6QfN8z5dZNNJ14rASpj/r3vJCgXPFIO6/8= после преобразование в base64

Comment: А в каком контексте используется этот функционал  в PHP ? Можете показать что у вас получается в результате $bin_key = pack("H*", 'e0sitcs5zd51wuauz8r65c1jqxtc1tsojt4mtk2lbd4ak2x2tf');

Comment: резульат в PHP - lmFaDyQtd6QfN8z5dZNNJ14rASpj/r3vJCgXPFIO6/8= после преобразование в base64

Answer (score 0):

```
Buffer('e0sitcs5zd51wuauz8r65c1jqxtc1tsojt4mtk2lbd4ak2x2tf').toString('hex')
```

> '65307369746373357a643531777561757a3872363563316a717874633174736f6a74346d746b326c626434616b3278327466'